# SVN folders are no longer under version control

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

During committing to svn server happened power loss on my side (commit was not completed). After turning on PC I found that previously checked out folders (and all files inside these folders) are no longer under version control. Thought .svn folder exist, but no commit/update/etc. possibility and folders/files doesn't have green/red symbol on it. See the picture. Is it possible to restore version control?

[image: folders unbinded from svn]

Comment: Have you run `svn cleanup` on the parent directory?

Comment: any update? have you tried my hack?

Answer (score 0):

Make a [checkout in a new working copy](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html), copy the data from old working copy (without the old .SVN folder) to the new Working Copy and replace all files. If the status is green for all files, the last commit was fully committed. If not, you can submit the still modified files in a 2nd commit to the repository.

Now use the new working copy and delete the old one.